# How to use shared_ptr to manage an object placed with placement new?

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-ptr

A fairly common thing I need to do is allot an object and some memory it'd like, in a strictly contagious region of memory together:

```
class Thing{
    static_assert(alignof(Thing) == alignof(uint32), "party's over");
public:
   
    ~Thing(){
        //// if only, but this would result in the equivalent of `free(danglingPtr)` being called
        //// as the second stage of shared_ptr calling `delete this->get()`, which can't be skipped I believe? 
        // delete [] (char*)this;
    }

    static Thing * create(uint32 count) {
        uint32 size = sizeof(Thing) + sizeof(uint32) * count; // no alignment concerns
        char * data = new char[size];
        return new (data)Thing(count);
    }
    
    static void destroy(Thing *& p) {
        delete [] (char*)p;
        p = NULL;
    }

    uint32 & operator[](uint32 index) {
        assert(index < m_count);
        return ((uint32*)((char*)(this + sizeof(Thing))))[index];
    }

private:
    Thing(uint32 count) : m_count(count) {};
    uint32 m_count;
};

int main(){
    {
        auto p = shared_ptr<Thing>(Thing::create(1));
        // how can I tell p how to kill the Thing?
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In `Thing::Create()` this is done with placement new into a section of memory.

I'd also like to have a shared pointer manage it in this case, using `auto p = shared_ptr<Thing>(Thing::create(1))`.  But If it calls the equivalent of `delete p.get()` when the ref count empties, that'd be undefined as it mismatches the type and, more importantly, mismatches plural new with singular delete.  I need it to delete in a special way.

Is there a way to easily set that up without defining an outside function?  Perhaps by having the shared pointer call `Thing::destroy()` when the ref count empties?  I know that shared pointer can accept a "deleter" as a template argument, but I'm unsure how to use it, or if it's even the proper way to address this?

Comment: What's the use case of combination with `shared_ptr` and `placement new`?

Comment: Regarding the use of a deleter, [`cppreference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr#Example) has an example.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin - this structure is normally used in a threadpool system with strict memory constraints, but I'd like to use the same structure in a less strict context if `shared_ptr` allows for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` accepts a deleter function as a second parameter, so you can use that to define how the managed object will be destroyed.

Here's a simplified example:

```cpp
class Thing
{
public:
    ~Thing()
    {
        std::cout << "~Thing\n";
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<Thing> create() {
        char * data = new char[sizeof(Thing)];
        Thing* thing = new (data) Thing{};
        return std::shared_ptr<Thing>{thing, &Thing::destroy};
    }
    
    static void destroy(Thing* p) {
        p->~Thing();
        delete [] (char*)p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto p = Thing::create();
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ccb7fb6056f3a8a)

Comment: I didn't think to return the shared pointer itself, that's a vast improvement, thank you